# Как можно реализовать настоящую многопоточность в PHP

Tags: php, многопоточность

К примеру у меня есть функция такая как ее запустить в многопотоке

$cou = count($akk);
    $i = 0;

```
while($i<$cou){echo $i;$i++;}
```

Результат выполнения в многопотоке должен быть примерно таким

> 1 2 3 4 5 6..... Без повторений

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать расширение pthreads. Хорошо описано [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/300952/).

Так же, можно использовать очереди, например RabbitMQ. Публиковать задачу в очередь в одном скрипте, и выполнять её множеством других скриптов.
Мануал по RabbitMQ на русском так же [есть на хабре.](https://habrahabr.ru/post/149694/)
Если не хочется разбираться с RabbitMQ, можно написать своё подобие сервиса для работы с очередями. Писать данные для выполнения в файл или в БД, запускать много обработчиков, которые будут по очереди брать задачи и выполнять. Только не забудьте позаботиться о конкурентности потоков, чтобы, когда один поток берёт задачу, другой не мог взять её же. (например, [flock()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.flock.php))

Comment: А без расширения никак?

Comment: Нативно php не поддерживает многопоточность. Написал ещё способ, выбирайте сами)

Comment: Ну либо запилить многопоточный обработчик на другом языке и дергать его через системный вызов